# How to turn on IE5 Quirks mode only for IE10?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, gwt, http-headers

I have a GWT application that displays normally in all browsers except IE10. I have found out that it can be displayed normally in IE10 with IE5 Quirks mode. The question is - how can I turn on automatically IE5 Quirks mode only for IE10 browser programmatically (for example, using HTML meta tags or something). I do not need that mode for any other browsers. The problem is that there are no conditional statements any more in IE10+, so I'm stuck here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Absolutely the wrong way to go about it

Comment: I understand that the best way is to make the site working normally under IE10, but I need to apply that quick fix asap...

Comment: Yeah, that 'quick fix' is to correctly program your website for IE10, and not rely on IE5 'quirks mode'. Do it once and do it properly.

Comment: That would be fine, but I m not the developer of this site, and right now I have an opened support ticket which I should fix...